# Is it possible to manage different github account for different projects in android studio?

Tags: github, android-studio

I am now using android studio to develop several applications.

And one of them exists in the repository of a different github account.

But, when I have two instance of android studio opened for two projects, and changed one github account in the VCS setting,  the setting of the other instance also changed. which is quite inconvenient. For I want these two projects shared in different repo from different account.

Hope I made my point clearly. Anyone have some idea about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can simply use command line or terminal  for any `push` or `pull`. Instead of using Android studio. If in case you do this way and SSH key is not configured you might be able to easily use two different account because it is just going to be varied `remote`